# Apache - How to deny directory but allow one file in that directory

Tags: security, apache, webserver

I try to configure my Apache .conf file to deny listing from a certain category, but I want to allow a specific file inside this category.
It appears that the Directory rule is "stronger" than the Files rule, so when using both - I can't access that certain file.

This is what I try:

```
<Directory /var/www/denied_directory>
     order deny,allow
     Deny From All
</Directory>

<Files safefile.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
</Files>
```

Answer (score 23):

It works perfectly if it is configured properly:

```
   <Directory /var/www/denied_directory>
        Order allow,deny
        <Files test.php>
           Order deny,allow
        </Files>
   </Directory>
```

Comment: Same here. 403 Forbidden. Why's this with 20 +votes?

Comment: Doesn't this need a  `Deny from all` line inside the directory directive and the `Allow from all` line inside the Files directive???

Answer (score 15):

In Apache 2.4, with an additional test on an environment variable for good measure:

See also: [Require Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require)

```
<Directory "/wikis/foswiki">

    Require all denied

    # Allow access to toplevel files ending in .html (in particular index.html) only 
    # (comment out if you don't care for this)

    <Files ~ "\.html$">

       <RequireAll>
          Require all granted
          Require not env blockAccess
       </RequireAll>

    </Files>

</Directory>
```

Answer (score 4):

put your files directive inside your directory directive.

Answer (score 2):

To allow a specific file when access is restricted by HTTP password. Be careful, password protection is defined on filesystem basis and specific allowed files are defined by URI. Updated for Apache 2.4.

```
<Directory /path/to/directory/>
    AuthName SecureArea
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /path/to/passwd-file
    Require user my-user

    SetEnvIf Request_URI "path/to/uri-allowed-1.php" allowedURL
    SetEnvIf Request_URI "path/to/uri-allowed-2.php" allowedURL
    Require env allowedURL
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a missing line in @acond's answer.  I think it needs `Allow`:

```
<Directory /var/www/denied_directory>
     order deny,allow
     Deny from All
    <Files safefile.php>
        order deny,allow
        Allow from All
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Since there is only one rule in each directive, I suspect the `order` lines may be irrelevant. Although maybe the outermost one is required, because there is more than one rule nested. (I'm new to apache configuration)

Answer (score 1):

Create an `.htaccess` file in the directory (folder) and use the block below:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all

<Files safefile.php>
   allow from all
</Files>
```

This will allow `../safefile.php` file but `../`.
If you want to allow `../` (for instance you need to have `../index.php`), then you should do this:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all

<FilesMatch ^(index\.php)?$>
    allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Are these directives still valid for Apache 2.4? I get internal server error when I use these

Comment: @taimuralam, I've tested these on Apache 2.2. I'm not sure about 2.4.