# Anyway protecting your site from external site scandir

Tags: php, .htaccess, security, scanning

Just came across to a website that lists all hidden files. I utilized Facebooks directory called: "hashtag/" and the results showed a whole bunch of files from http://www.facebook.com/hashtag/

Here's the website that does this: https://pentest-tools.com/website-vulnerability-scanning/discover-hidden-directories-and-files

So my main question here is, is there any way to protect your site from being scanned by another website showing secret files like: **tokens.php, sessions.php, templates/, models/ configs/**...etc???

This got me really worried now, just say we are making a website that holds important files and structures and if someone wanted to see what we're holding in that specific folder, is there any kind of way to prevent this from showing from that website or any other sites that does this operation?

I know you can do this by .htaccess, but could you show me an example for preventing scanning on multiple folders?

Comment: When I try to search facebook.com/hashtag/ it does not find any files or directories?

Comment: Have you chose: get files extensions for: **.php**???

Comment: Yep, not a single file was returned.

Comment: Erm OK, I'll post a image just to prove it to you and others, just a sec

Comment: @OptimusCrime Here's the links: 1) http://www.mediafire.com/view/pzpoy7ll4x90kaa/Capture_240.jpg 2) http://www.mediafire.com/view/nsg3og2l5n6nvne/Capture_234.jpg 3) http://www.mediafire.com/view/nt0ewe8ddoda8b4/Capture_235.jpg 4) http://www.mediafire.com/view/23z03ed6d6gvdve/Capture_236.jpg 5) http://www.mediafire.com/view/yabwcn52w8w2y6x/Capture_237.jpg 6) http://www.mediafire.com/view/e4zxcczbca240o7/Capture_238.jpg 7) http://www.mediafire.com/view/2nrmy7ae9z1sqtk/Capture_239.jpg

Answer (score 5):

The main option is `Indexes` you can turn them off in your `.htaccess` with

```
Options -Indexes
```

The second option is blocking `Deny`

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
```

Say you have a folder called `inc` that holds some files that you don't want accessible via a url but you want your other PHP scripts to be able to include them you toss this rule in an `.htaccess` file in your `inc` folder.

Here is a link to a great resource on `.htaccess` rules https://github.com/phanan/htaccess

Comment: Thank you for your time @cmorrissey :) that helped a lot, it's just scary when someone is viewing hidden structures when they're not supposed to :P

Answer (score 1):

One common approach is to put files that are not directly accessed below the web root, so they are inaccessible from the web.

For example, if you have your web root at  `var/www/html`, place your source code outside `html` and it will be impossible to load from the internet. This, however, requires you to use some sort of loading/requiring the files in your framework, but that is pretty common these days. See [PSR-4: Autoloading](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/).

The tool you linked to does not have a "magic" way of finding files, as blocking/hiding files with Apache is absolute, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243677/apache-how-to-deny-directory-but-allow-one-file-in-that-dirctory) answer for more .htaccess details. The tool simply tries a series of words, and common file names, and checks for a valid 200 response. Unless you move your files outside the web root, this would be impossible to defend against.

As you are saying, this is possible deny access to directories and files with .htaccess, and also turn off file listing, however you should note that .htaccess settings are inherited from directory to directory, which means that if you block all access at the root level, this will be applied to every single file and directory it contains.